# UV4L on Raspbian not working

Tags: camera, uv4l

I've installed the UV4L video for linux framework for the PI, and it installs fine but when running the following dd command to capture an image

```
dd if=/dev/video1 of=snapshot.jpeg bs=11M count=1
```

I'm getting this error:

```
dd: opening `/dev/video1': Interrupted system call
```

I followed the instruction on it's website http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14

Anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo rpi-update

then working fine

BRG

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.